# Async Data Loading in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I like to pull in some remote data when rendering a ractive template. Due to the async nature of the request no data makes it into output. How can I make that happen?

```
 var ractive = new Ractive({
    debug: true,
        el: 'container',
        template: '#template',
        data: 
        {   
            chapters:chapters,
                    load_text: function(path)
                    {
                         $.get(path, function( text ) {                            
                             return text;
                          });
                    }                    
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A couple of solutions come to mind;

Create the Ractive object, make the request, and then call 'set' on the ractive object when you have data.

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    debug: true,
    el: 'container',
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        chapters: chapters,
        load_text: ''
    }
});

$.get(path, function( text ) {
    ractive.set('load_text', text);
});
```

Alternatively, and this is not recommended, you could cause your request to become synchronous.

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    debug: true,
    el: 'container',
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        chapters: chapters,
        load_text: function(path) {
            $.ajax({
                url: path,
                success : function (text) {
                    return text;
                },
                async : false
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is actually how we load data with our R components in production.

Comment: @TeoChoongPing do you have a full example? 
I have a lot of jquery plugins on page and have problems of when calling what code ( in what order)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your call to `$.get` isn't returning any values, is because the function that you pass it is a callback (a function passed as a parameter to another function, to be executed upon the first function's completion, without blocking).

The actual `$.get` function returns nothing. The reason you pass it a callback is so that, when it's done running, it can call that callback (with the result of `$.get` as a parameter).   Also, unless you're calling `ractive.data.load_text()` somewhere in your application the function that you've assigned to `load_text` will never run.

What worries me is that the code you posted demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding of how Javascript (and in particular, asynchronous operations in Javascript) work.  I recommend doing some reading on callbacks (I've posted some resources below).  Good luck!

javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Also, when you're ready to graduate from callbacks, here's an article on promises in jQuery: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises--net-24135

Comment: thanks! I understand js and was simply looking for a way to make it work with ractive.